# Не обновляется база данных через адаптер

Tags: c#, sql

```
private void update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            table_concurentTableAdapter.Update(parserDataSet.Table_concurent);


        }
```

Провожу изменение в таблице datagrid
Далее обновляю базу данных а данных там нет

Comment: Ага, а файл базы находится в проекте со свойствами `Content` и `Copy always`, да?

Comment: Действие при сборке -Содержание , Копировать в выходной каталог -всегда копировать

Comment: Ну, вот и файл базы из корня проекта, каждый раз перезаписывает файл, который лежит в /bin/Debug. Т.е. нужно исправить свойство не `всегда копировать` , а на другое, не знаю как на русском `Copy if newer`

Comment: Есть значение свойства копировать более позднюю версию, но это ни к чему не приводит. Воз и нынче там.

Comment: `а данных там нет` - как вы это поняли? Данные при перезапуске исчезают? Если запускать из bin\debug напрямую, данные пропадают?

Comment: Команда для update в адаптере прописана?

Comment: нет наверно не прописана((